# INSERT INTO goes wrong PHP CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image: screenshot]

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `waitinglist` (`reserver`, `roomNumber`, `hotelNumber`, `queueDepth`) 
        VALUES(".$this->db->escape($reserver).", ".$room.", ".$i.", ".$queueDepth+1.")";
$this->db->query($sql);
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: _You mean appart from_ Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Are all 4 columns numeric, or are some of them text columns

Answer (score 0):

Use better editor/IDE with error highlighting, this is easy to solve syntax error:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `waitinglist` (`reserver`, `roomNumber`, `hotelNumber`, `queueDepth`) 
        VALUES(".$this->db->escape($reserver).", ".$room.", ".$i.", ".($queueDepth+1).")";
```

Comment: or simply `", " . $queueDepth+1 . ")";`